# Подключение между собой заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток . Проблема в том что не пойму как подключить заголовочные файлы правильно. Есть несколько классов(пусть будет 5 классов, тогда 5 заголовочных и 5 срр) . Есть отдельный файл для описания функций для данных классов.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ( то есть с использванием этих классов).А в этих же пяти классах нужно использовать файл, в котором описаны функции. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать , а то сейчас только ошибка redefenition ..

Comment: Вы наверное забыли include guard?

Comment: Наверное, было бы правильным сделать подключение нужного заголовочного файла где-нибудь в самом верху иерархии подключений, не забыв при этом активировать защиту от повторных включений( я имею ввиду define...endif )

Comment: Я пробовал с include guard , pragma once . Но при этом в заголовочном файле где описаны доп. функции по работе с классами пишет undeclared identifier